Old TV episode about a rich man and his guests trapped in his high-tech underground bunker after a nuclear disaster
This was black & white, so could've been The Twilight Zone or any other old science fiction series.
Plot: A rich man, proud of his high-tech underground bunker, invites guests over to show it off. Suddenly, a nuclear disaster occurs, and he's forced to seal the bunker, trapping everyone inside. As tensions rise, the guests realize that they may be stuck underground forever. Ultimately, they come up to the surface and see that the world has in fact been destroyed.
Everyone is going to suggest "The Shelter" from Twilight Zone, and that's a great episode, but this one is definitely not that.

Reminds me of the beginning of Farnham's Freehold, by Heinlein. Not exactly, of course.

Might it be "One More Pallbearer" from The Twilight Zone?

Millionaire Paul Radin tries to convince three people who wronged him in the past to apologize to him by offering them shelter from a staged and phony nuclear war scenario.

The twist is that

 After the guests decide to brave the "destroyed" world rather than deal with him, he finds out that nuclear war did happen. Except... it turns out that he's just psychologically broken and war did not happen.

Episode



